# Inkscape Icon view: half pixel issue

Tags: icons, pixel, inkscape

I made a 24×24px square in Inkscape. I don’t understand why does the 24×24 icon view shows me a square with a gray pixel at its bottom? Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: My page’s size was the default A4 and was in millimetres. It should be set in pixels!